# sendmail restart fail [exim abandoned: unknown,malformed, or incomplete option -L]

Tags: exim, failed

When I restart Sendmail services, I see the following:

```
[root@]# service sendmail restart
Shutting down sm-client:                                   [FAILED]
Shutting down sendmail:                                    [  OK  ]
Starting sendmail:                                         [  OK  ]
Starting sm-client: exim abandoned: unknown,malformed, or incomplete option -L [FAILED]
```

How can i do to fix this please?
i'm on linux CentOS

Comment: When did this problem start?  Did you recently edit the configs?  What if you stop, and then start the service?  Same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use sendmail startup scripts to start exim.

The script fails to start second daemon process (sm-client) which is not needed by exim.